# Can we make the 1st tab not to be selected when we are launching a tab based applicaion?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Usually when a tab based app is launched, automatically control goes to the 1st tab. Is there any way such that the 1st tab's view will be shown but without the 1st tab being selected?

Comment: No, and that's a good thing. That would violate basic UI principles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

before adding tabBarController to your window write

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Here it will show 3rd tab's view as application starts... (0 1 2)